# How can I visit descendant nodes in a SonarQube custom rule?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I am attempting to write a SonarQube JavaScript custom rule. The rule should see that a for loop is not empty (i.e. has more than 0 statements in the for block body).

I've extended the **DoubleDispatchVisitorCheck** class, and overridden the **visitForStatement** method. Within that method I'm unsure of how to determine how many descendants the for statement has.

```
  @Override
  public void visitForStatement(ForStatementTree tree) {
      StatementTree statement = tree.statement();
      // How to see tree or statement descendants?
      super.visitForStatement(tree);
  }
```

The [best documentation I've located](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+JavaScript#CustomRulesforJavaScript-Overview) does not go in depth on how to traverse more than a single node in the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (statement.is(Kind.BLOCK) && ((BlockTree) statement).statements().isEmpty()) {
  addIssue(tree, "message");
}
```

And btw there is similar rule https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=javascript%3AEmptyBlock

Comment: +1 this was very helpful. I'd like to also add a link to the sonar-javascript source as a source of more concrete code examples:

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript